# phpmyadin loads for several minutes

Tags: php, performance, phpmyadmin

I got the problem that my phpmyadmin needs alot of time to actually be loaded.

The database is small and I do not know how to fix this issue.

Has anyone experienced with this kind of situation and can help me out

Comment: Maybe some voodoo or something? How do you think we will be able to answer such a question without any information whatsoever. Please extend your answer with some log files, server information, anything. Maybe you will be simply the best sometime ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin EXTREMELY slow when loading innoDB database main page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325229/phpmyadmin-extremely-slow-when-loading-innodb-database-main-page)

Comment: Where an I see the log files