# phpMyAdmin takes long time to load

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

It load the data very slow it take more than 10 seconds to load the database views the table data. I try that but it's take too long time to load the data in phpmyadmin

Comment: This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21327364/3081659

Comment: i try that before adding this question but its not any changes

Comment: is there any another solution for this

Comment: I don't think so. Because the main issue is up to date Phpmyadmin.

Comment: You could always use SequelPro or MySQL Workbench instead of using phpmyadmin. You'll find it'll time out when trying to upload large data imports to phpmyadmin because its browser loaded. SequelPro or Workbench are downloaded to your system and do not timeout.

Comment: @Jeevan Why don't you use SQL Yog ? It is pretty good.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?